# python2.7-dev won't install

Tags: python

I am trying to get Python.h into my /usr/include/python2.7 directory, so I run

> $ sudo apt install python-dev

which informs me that these will be installed:
   libpython-dev libpython2.7 libpython2.7-dev python2.7-dev

So far, so good.  Then I get this output:

```
Err:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7 amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libpython2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
Err:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 python2.7-dev amd64 2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/libpython2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python2.7/python2.7-dev_2.7.15-4ubuntu4~18.04.1_amd64.deb 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.24 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

So I run it with the --fix-missing option:

> $ sudo apt install python-dev --fix-missing

and get the same ouput but with this at the end:

> E: Aborting install.

How do I fix that?

Comment: Which OS and which version of the OS? Does it match Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: According to the error message it is looking for version 18.04.1, but in the repository there is 18.04.2. Maybe try an `apt-get update`?

Answer (score 2):

This worked great for me.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234856/broken-packages-problem-trying-to-install-python-dev

Delete the apt cache using

```
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get update
```

Comment: Don't forget `sudo`.